# Show that this entire function is polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $ |f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^*$
$$
g(z)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right).
$$
So 
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\;|g(z)|=+\infty.
$$
Obviously, $0$ is not a removable singularity.

Now by the [Casorati-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), $0$ is not an essential singularity either. Indeed, take $r>0$ such that $|g(z)|\geq 1$ for all $0<|z|<r$. Then $g(z\;;\;0<|z|<r\})$ is certainly not dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @mrf, it is actually easy to see that this implies $0$ is a pole for $g$. It suffices to use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities adequately. Indeed $h(z)=1/g(z)$ is holomorphic and bounded in some $\{z\;;\;0<|z|<r\}$ with limit $0$ at $0$, so $0$ is a removable singularity of $h$ and a zero of the holomorphic extension of $h$. Factor $h(z)=z^nk(z)$ with $k$ holomorphic and $k(0)\neq 0$. The result follows. And this is indeed more elementary than Casorati-Weierstrass.
So keep the Casorati-Weierstrass argument for weaker assumptions such as the ones I mention below.

So $0$ must be a pole. Hence the Laurent series of $g$ at $0$ is of the form
$$
g(z)=\frac{a_n}{z^n}+\ldots+\frac{a_1}{z}+a_0.
$$
Note that there are no positive powers of $z$ because this comes from the power series of $f$.

The result follows clearly by going back to $f$.

**Edit:** Note the same proof works if we simply assume that $f$ is entire and there exist $\alpha>0$ and $M>0$ such that
$$
|f(z)|\geq \alpha\qquad \forall |z|\geq M.
$$

Of course, there could be even weaker assumptions like there exists $M>0$ such that $f(\{z\;;\; |z|>M\})$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$ and the proof would still work.

Comment: This is a good answer +1, but is it possible to do with more elementary tools than Casorati-Weierstrass?

Comment: @user58512 Thanks. Maybe, since the assumption is much stronger than what is really needed to apply Casorati-Weierstrass. Let's wait and see.

Comment: Since $|g|\to \infty$ as $z\to 0$, we see that $0$ is a pole directly (without Weierstrass-Casorati).

Comment: @Seirios Thanks for the edit, you made me understand that it was possible to do this. After six months...it was high time.

Comment: Often this property is used as the very definition of *pole*, but even with other plausible definitions, it's straight-forward to see that an isolated singularity is a pole iff $|f| \to\infty$ at the point in question.

Comment: @mrf: This basically shifts the burden to Riemann's theorem on removable singularities, which, perhaps, is slightly more elementary than Liouville and Casorati-Weierstrass.

Comment: @mrf Oh boy, you're right. This is easy.

Comment: @julien: I agree that we can write $g(z)= \sum\limits_{k=-n}^{\infty} c_kz^k$, so $f(z)= \sum\limits_{k=-n}^{\infty} c_kz^{-k}$, but how do you know the behaviour of this series for $z \to 0$ to deduce that $c_k=0$ if $k>0$?

Comment: @Seirios $f$ entire so $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_nz^n$, so $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_nz^{-n}$. $0$ is a pole for $g$ so $g(z)=c_nz^{-n}+\ldots+c_0$. So $f(z)=c_nz^n+\ldots+c_0$.

Comment: @Seirios These hold for all $z\neq 0$. Now if $f$ is entire, it is continuous at $0$, so the last equality holds also at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The set of zeroes of $f$ is bounded and discrete, hence finite and this allows us to find a polynomial $p$ such that $f(z)=p(z)g(z)$ for some entire function $g\colon \mathbb C\to\mathbb C^\times$. What scenarios can happen with $g(z)$ as $z\to\infty$?

Comment: If a set of points is bounded and discrete, can you then conclude is finite? Any sequence that converges is bounded and discrete, and infinite, like $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$

Comment: @GitGud Yes thanks.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Some people take discrete to mean *closed* and discrete for which the statement that boundedness implies finiteness is true. The set of zeroes of $f$ is clearly closed.

Comment: Hm, upon rereading I think that whoever upvoted me here should be ashamed :9