# How to solve this MCQ?

Tags: analysis

[image]

I'm clueless how to start with the solution to this problem.

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311892/show-that-this-entire-function-is-polynomial

Answer (score 1):

First show that $f(z)$ has finitely many zeros (hint: zeros cannot accumulate); then show that this implies that $f(z)$ is a polynomial (both are good exercises about entire functions). The answer then follows easily.

Comment: To the O.P.:  If  $f$ is entire and $A\in \mathbb C$ and if $\{z: f(z)=A\}$ contains an infinite bounded subset then $f(z)=A$ for all $z$.  But if $ \{z:f(z)=A\}$ is unbounded   then $|f(z)|$ does not $\to \infty$ as $|z|\to \infty.$